# Pipe colored output of command into the less command

Tags: bash, pipe, less-unix

I have the following function to print colored output from a command:

```
faketty () {
            script -qfec "$(printf "%s " "$@")" > out; less -r out; rm out;
}
```

I can't pipe the color output of the `script` command directly into `less -r` because the formatting gets messed up. Saving it to a file as shown works. Wondering if I can eliminate the need to save to a file.

UPDATE: I'm running less version 481 (GNU regular expressions).

Comment: `"$(printf "%s " "$@")"` is the same as `"$*"`, by the way.

Comment: Does `less -R` work any better?

Comment: No, same result with uppercase "R"

Comment: And the original command is `faketty cheat <command>`. See https://github.com/cheat/cheat/issues/451 for reference.

Comment: Use `s` to save the piped output to a file, then `diff` it against the working file. What's different?

Comment: s? Is that an option? I don't see it as an option for `script` or `less`. Actually, it is an option for `less` but gets rid of blank lines.

Comment: Oh, is that uppercase "S"? For chopping long lines?

Comment: A key inside less: "`s filename` - Save the input to a file. This only works if the input is a pipe, not an ordinary file."

Comment: OK, "s <file>" gave me a text file with escaped color codes in it. Let me see how that differs from piping the output of script directly to a file.

Comment: Interesting. Visually, they look the same. Same escape codes. And when I open up the file generated with "s" with `less -r` it looks clean.

Comment: What if you press Ctrl-L to redraw the screen in less? Does that make it look better?

Comment: Interesting. I tried that before and it didn't do anything. This time, however, I hit return after doing ^L and the formatting cleared up.

Comment: Only problem is, though, that after I hit return, less is stuck. Scrolling with "j" and "k" doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, if I hit return after each time I do "j" or "k", it will scroll up and down one line.

Comment: `less -R` will be better behaved.

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: Whoa, I twiddled with the script a bit. Now ^L takes things back to normal. Getting closer.

Comment: Interesting. When I have shell var LESSCHARSET=utf-8 ^L breaks again.

Comment: Got it. Jesus. After lots of trial and error, I figured out how to get the screen to clear itself:

`faketty cheat $1 $2 | less +Gg -r` did the trick. Basically, `+Gg` moves screen to bottom and then back to top. For whatever reason, this clears up the mess.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this works but it does:

```
faketty () {
            script -qfec "$(printf "%s " "$@")" dev/null;
}

faketty cheat $1 $2 | less +Gg -r;
```

Moving the pipe outside of the function helped for whatever reason. However, I still had to hit `^L` to clean up the mess. The `+Gg` moves the file to the last line and then the first line. This somehow "cleans up" the formatting without having to hit `^L`.